# Get value from textbox on .aspx page of server side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am developing a Web Application in C#. In which the `Default.aspx` page runs on startup, on that page a JavaScript is loaded(run) which creates a simple textbox and button.

**Both textbox and button are created by the JavaScript.**

When I click on button it gets the value from textbox. Now I want the value on `Default.aspx.cs` side.

**Problem:**

How can I get this textbox value to the sever side (`Default.aspx.cs`)

Answer (score 2):

some options:

1. create a runat="server" based hidden field and assign textbox value to this.
2. append the value in the querystring and access it server side using Request.QueryString

Comment: yes, it is more preferable than query string since data is not easily visible.

Answer (score 1):

1) If your textbox does not have runat="server" attribute, you can use the following method.

Create a hidden field which has runat="server" i.e. its a server-side control. Assign the value of this textbox to this hidden field on your button click(in javascript).

You can then access the value of the hidden field on the server-side.

2) If your textbox has runat="server" attribute, you can use the following method.

```
Request.Form["Name of Textbox"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve value from `Request.Form` collection.

```
 string strValue = Request.Form["Name of Control"].ToString();
```